# How can i drag a view over an view that has an html content in Open Laszlo 5.0?

Tags: drag, openlaszlo, lzx

I am trying to drag an content over an html content in OL5.0. 
the observations are 
i am able to drag from the laszlo component to html component without any problem.
I am able to drag from laszlo to html to laszlo.
But, if i drag that view to html and then release it and then drag from html it's not working.

This is the code.

```
<canvas>

   <view bgcolor="green" width="20" height="20" onmousedown="dragger.setAttribute('applied', true);this.bringToFront();" onmouseup="dragger.setAttribute('applied', false)">
                <dragstate name="dragger"/>

    </view>  

    <view y="50" width="100%" height="300" bgcolor="blue" onmousedown="res.apply()" onmouseup="res.remove()">
        <resizestate name="res"/>
        <dragstate name="drg"/>
        <text width="100%" bgcolor="gray" onmousedown="parent.drg.apply()" onmouseup="parent.drg.remove()">Drag here</text>
        <html id="ht" src="http://localhost:8080/lps-5.0.x/htmlTest/resource/text.html" x="15" y="15" width="${parent.width - 30}" height="${parent.height - 30}"/>
    </view>         
</canvas>
```

Comment: I remember that Max Carlson had a demo of that working back in 2007, where you could drag a view from an OpenLaszlo app in an iframe into the main page. Never saw the source code for it, and don't know if that was actually added to the platform.

Comment: But that's - in my eyes - one of the key problems of the DHTML runtime: That it is impossible to have two OpenLaszlo canvas apps running in one page without using an iFrame.

Comment: @r.bitter: So, is  it possible like to create an invisible view over the html area like a mask when i click the drag object. The objective is that i'll be still dragging over an openlaszlo app only in this case. Will it work?

Comment: The demo I saw was 5 year ago, and I never had a chance to look at the code back then. So I don't know how it was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I have been programming in OpenLaszlo 2006 and when I have tried to use the OpenLaszlo <html> class it has been very unstable, buggy and unpredictable. I do not recommend using that particular class in any application.